# Determining miss and hits on cache

Tags: c, caching, architecture

Consider the following matrix transpose routine:

```
typedef int array[4][4];

void transpose(array dst, array src){
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for (j=0;j<4;j++){
            dst[j][i] = src[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Assume this code runs on a machine with the following properties

- `sizeof(int)` = 4
- The src array starts at the address of 0 and the dst array starts at the address 64
- There is a single L! data cache that is direct-mapped, write-through, writeallocate, with a block size of 16 bytes
- The cache has a total size of 32 data bytes and the cache is initially empty.
- Access to the src and dst array are the only sources of read and write misses.

I am tasked with determining whether each access to each array is a cache hit or miss

I got for the dst

```
_____________________________________
|    Col 0    Col 1    Col 2    Col 3|
|Row0    m        m        m        m|
|Row1    m        m        m        m|
|Row2    m        m        m        m|
|Row3    m        m        m        m|
______________________________________
```

and for the src array

```
_____________________________________
|    Col 0    Col 1    Col 2    Col 3|
|Row0    m        h        h        h|
|Row1    m        h        h        h|
|Row2    m        h        h        h|
|Row3    m        h        h        h|
______________________________________
```

Are these correct? Asking around with other students, everyone seems to have gotten different answers.

Comment: Does `dest` really have address 63, which isn't word-aligned?

Comment: Whoops, mistyped. It has 64, will edit my post.

Comment: And where will `i`, `j`, `dst`(the passed as the argument) and `src`(the pointer passed as the argument) be stored? What is the actual machine language to be executed? (They may be stored on registers thanks to the optimization)

Comment: Ok, how would the problem be tackled with the way you mentioned?

Comment: I think this part also makes it safe to make this assumption: *Access to the src and dst array are the only sources of read and write misses.* Maybe it'd help to emphasize that or put it in bold.

Comment: I believe what you have is correct but need an expert to jump in. Each iteration accesses an aligned row of both `dst` and `src`, each iteration will miss for `dst` since it's cycling rows there, `src` will have a compulsory miss on the first column but not for second, third, and fourth.

Comment: Maybe re-make the example so that both variables are declared at file scope?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cache Memory Optimization Array Transpose: C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549940/cache-memory-optimization-array-transpose-c)